# In a Shell scripts, check version of installed package, make a decision based on output

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, debian, shell, shell-script

Looking to write a cross distro / cross version shell script that makes sure a forced version of PHP is installed

Example: Ubuntu 12.04 has 5.3, Ubuntu 13.10 has 5.5, Debian 7 has 5.4

I need this script, when run on a distro that has an old version of PHP, to update the repo to point to a package for 5.4, and if the distro has too new of a version, can downgrade to 5.4 appropriately.

Im still not entirely comprehensive of Shell/Terminals technical limit of what you can do with it, but ill be perfectly frank that im still not totally used to existing tools

The best I can think at the moment is: `php -v | grep "PHP 5"` but that returns a bunch of potentially changeable granular characters `(PHP 5.4.4-14+deb7u5 (cli) (built: Oct  3 2013 09:24:58) )`. Im not sure what to pipe to after this to extract out the characters im interested in

Im not sure if im being totally clear, im not sure how to ask this.. Basically, in an automated shell script for Linux distros, how do I extract the PHP version (and just the PHP version number preferably) and make a decision based on that output.

This line ended up doing pretty dang good

```
php -v | grep "PHP 5" | sed 's/.*PHP \([^-]*\).*/\1/' | cut -c 1-3
```

Bit long in the tooth, but gives me "5.3", "5.4", and "5.5" which is exactly what I need to work with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try some regular expressions maybe:

```
php -v|grep --only-matching --perl-regexp "5\.\\d+\.\\d+"
```

For version number comparison, I have used a bash script in the past from [Bash. How compare two strings in “version” format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4025065/259953)

#### Full script

I decided to go with your approach, because it seemed a little safer. I also added an example of how to apply the referenced script here. So here's the full example:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Version number compare helper function
# Created by Dennis Williamson (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023830/bash-how-compare-two-strings-in-version-format)
function compareVersions() {
  if [[ $1 == $2 ]]
  then
    return 0
  fi
  local IFS=.
  local i ver1=($1) ver2=($2)
  # fill empty fields in ver1 with zeros
  for ((i=${#ver1[@]}; i<${#ver2[@]}; i++))
  do
    ver1[i]=0
  done
  for ((i=0; i<${#ver1[@]}; i++))
  do
    if [[ -z ${ver2[i]} ]]
    then
      # fill empty fields in ver2 with zeros
      ver2[i]=0
    fi
    if ((10#${ver1[i]} > 10#${ver2[i]}))
    then
      return 1
    fi
    if ((10#${ver1[i]} < 10#${ver2[i]}))
    then
      return 2
    fi
  done
  return 0
}

if ! hash php 2>&-; then
  echo "php is not installed!"
  exit 1
fi

PHP_VERSION=$(php -v | grep "PHP 5" | sed 's/.*PHP \([^-]*\).*/\1/' | cut -c 1-3)
echo "Installed PHP version: '$PHP_VERSION'"

set +e errexit
compareVersions $PHP_VERSION 5.4
_versionsEqual=$?
set -e errexit

case $_versionsEqual in
  0)
    # Versions equal, nothing to do
    echo "The installed version is 5.4 and doesn't need to be adjusted."
    ;;
  1)
    # Installed version is newer than 5.4
    echo "The installed version is newer than 5.4 and needs to be downgraded."
    ;;
  2)
    # Installed version is older then 5.4
    echo "The installed version is older than 5.4 and needs to be upgraded."
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: This works perfectly too

Comment: I would write you a more complete example, but a cat is hogging my chair.

Comment: @DJDarkViper: I've now added the example